# Which event I should listen to know when our bot user / app is added/invited to client slack channel

Tags: slack-api

I am working on a use case where I want to know when my bot user / slack app is added to private channel of client workspace . Which event I should listen to.

app_mention event is not invoked when app/bot user is invited or added to channel.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to listen to the [`member_joined_channel`](https://api.slack.com/events/member_joined_channel) event. It will fire once the bot is invited into a private or public channel.

If you listen to bot events only you will receive this event for all invites happening in all channels your bot is a member of.

It contains the user ID of the invited user, so you can easily filter those that involve only your bot directly.

Example from documentation:

```
{
    "type": "member_joined_channel",
    "user": "W06GH7XHN",
    "channel": "C0698JE0H",
    "channel_type": "C",
    "team": "T024BE7LD",
    "inviter": "U123456789"
}
```

Comment: This event will be fired only when our bot is added  or any member added to the channel?

Comment: For any member and more. I updated my answer with more details.

Comment: I think bot user is different for different workspace for same app installation, How can I filter or know that bot user belongs to my app .